# defining and chaining tasks separately

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I was hoping that I could somehow define and then chainem up in a nice way to get some code similar to this:

```
Task ShowLoadNotificationTask = new Task( () => ShowLoadNotification(frm) );
Task LoadAllWorkOrdersTask = new Task(() => LoadAllWorkOrders());
Task CloseLoadNotificationTask = new Task(() => CloseLoadNotificationTask(frm));

ShowLoadNotificationTask.ContinueWith( LoadAllWorkOrdersTask );
LoadAllWorkOrdersTask..ContinueWith(CloseLoadNotificationTask);

ShowLoadNotificationTask.Start();
```

Of course the above code is not correct, but how to get something working similar to above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to independently construct `Task` instances and then later combine them together into a single `Task`.  If so then what you are looking for is the `Unwrap` extension method defined in System.Core

```
Task parent = ShowLoadNotificationTask
  .ContinueWith(_ => LoadAllWorkOrdersTask)
  .Unwrap()
  .ContinueWith(_ => CloseLoadNotificationTask)
  .Unwrap();
```

The `Unwrap` method takes a `Task<Task>` and returns back a `Task` (the same goes for `Task<Task<T>>`.  This allows you to return a `Task` as the continuation of an existing `Task` and get back the original `Task` type you returned.